# Using the Data Source tool in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

I created an access DB and I then used the visual studio 2010 import function to include the database in my project, it also created a DataSet but I am having trouble figuring out how to extract data from the DataSet.

For example I try and use "BookCSharpDataSet.BookDataTable" but there are no methods for me to remove the data from the data table or even manipulate it. Any ideas on how to get the information out?

Comment: http://www.google.com is more than enough for you

Comment: You're asking for a tutorial. Try http://windowsclient.net/

Comment: Have a look at these links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171893.aspx which explains task based approach for access http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186197(v=vs.80).aspx  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/simple_movie_database.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to fill  an instance of your DataTable with data from the database. That will fill its rows with data, with columns that you can access and update.

Did your DataSet come with TableAdapters below the tables? Try calling their methods on an instance of your DataSet.

```
BookCSharpDataSet ds = new BookCSharpDataSet();
```

For further info: [an old tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/15/Building-a-DAL-using-Strongly-Typed-TableAdapters-and-DataTables-in-VS-2005-and-ASP.NET-2.0.aspx)